# Getting Maven site plugin working when in profile of multi-module project?

Tags: java, maven, multi-module, maven-site-plugin

I am attempting to build a full site for my multi-module project in one command that I can execute in Jenkins. However when I build it, the submodule javadocs appear in the site root (site/apidocs instead of site/submodule/apidocs). All the links from the parent to submodule are broken as well.

Organization is the standard

```
pom.xml
submodule/pom.xml
```

Parent POM contains:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            ... Various unrelated plugins ...
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>complete-build</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <!--JavaDoc setup for Jars-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <defaultAuthor>Leon Blakey</defaultAuthor>
                        <defaultVersion>${project.version}</defaultVersion>
                        <sourcepath>target/delombok</sourcepath>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!--Deploy site with Mercurial (Hg)-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency><!-- add support for scm -->
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                            <artifactId>wagon-scm</artifactId>
                            <version>2.4</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-hg</artifactId>
                            <version>1.8.1</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <configuration>
                        <reportPlugins>
                            <!--JavaDoc setup for Site-->
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>2.9.1</version>
                                <configuration>
                                    <defaultAuthor>Leon Blakey</defaultAuthor>
                                    <defaultVersion>${project.version}</defaultVersion>
                                    <sourcepath>target/delombok</sourcepath>
                                    <show>public</show>
                                </configuration>
                            </plugin>
                            ... Checkstyle, PMD, Findbugs, etc ...
                        </reportPlugins>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

The submodule POM just contains the skeleton plugin definitions for pluginManagement.

When I try to build a site (both on my local machine and Jenkins) I run from the parent

```
 mvn clean install site-deploy -Pcomplete-build
```

With the above setup, what would cause a submodule to dump its site files in the site root (site/) instead of the submodule directory (site/submodule)? Do I need to use the stanging commands (which I'm avoiding since it breaks the release process)? Is it simply impossible to build a multi-module site in one command?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [maven-reactor-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-reactor-plugin/index.html) to trigger building at the submodule level.